# How to identify transaction as full reversal or partial reversal transaction by inspecting ISO8583 fields

Tags: java, payment-processing, iso8583, jpos

I want to identify if transaction 0420 message is full reversal or partial reversal, How to do it? Should we say F95 (Replacement amount) is not set if it is full reversal.

Question:
Which field identifies transaction as a full reversal or partial reversal?
Do we need original transaction as well (0200 tran request) or 0420 itself contains enough information to identify the reversal category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on your endpoint specs.

We have some systems that sends you a replacement amount in field 95, some others in field 30 (which is actually for fees) but the basic idea is what you say, if you have a replacement amount, it's a partial reversal.

In ISO-8583 v2003 you've got data element 24 (Function Code) with specific values for accurate and estimated replacement amounts.